# I would like to calculate days between 2 date in days with condition

Tags: python, datetime, date-difference

This is my code :

```py
df["mois0"]=pd.to_datetime("01/10/2021")
df["mois1"]=pd.to_datetime("31/10/2021")
def calculAbsMois(datedebut, datefin, d0, d1):
    if datedebut<=d0 & datefin>=d0:
        if datefin >d1 :
            return d1.day - d0.day +1
        else : return datefin.day - d0.day +1
     elif datedebut< d1 & datefin>d1:
        return d1.day - datedebut.day +1
     elif datedebut>=d0 & datefin<=d1:
        return datefin.day - datedebut.day +1
```

and I apply my fonction :

```py
df['abs_202110'] = calculAbsMois(df["De"],df["-"],df["mois0"],df["mois1"])
```

And this is my error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'DatetimeArray' and 'DatetimeArray'
```

Comment: Show the entire error trace so we can see where the error occurred.

Comment: You're passing an entire column to the function, not a single date.